# Loading postgres data in batches C#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I have large table in postgres (around 30GB) and I am trying to load the data and put it in cache. Since that's a lot of data I am doing it in batches:

```
    private IEnumerable<Data> ReadData(int v)
    {
        var sql = $@"
            SELECT id,version, content, created,
            FROM data WHERE version > @version ORDER BY version
            LIMIT @batchSize OFFSET @offset";

        var offset = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var batch = _db.Execute(Map, sql, _db.CreateParameter("version", v),
                _db.CreateParameter("batchSize", _batchSize),
                _db.CreateParameter("offset", offset));

            var hasData = false;
            foreach (var v in batch)
            {
                yield return v;
                hasData = true;
            }

            if (!hasData)
                break;

            offset += _batchSize;
        }
    }
```

It's working quite slowly (I'll look into whether I need to increase memory, but now I am testing with only 3GB) But I was wondering if there are ways to improve my code and load faster?

Comment: Is your bottleneck getting the query results over the network?

Comment: yes, @gunr2171. At least right now it looks like this

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: This is a typical use case for a server side cursor: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html

Comment: I'd suggest using `DataReader`, for a similar case in the past I used that for fetching data. Less stress memory-wise.